# Generation online 3D map from a RGB Camera

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, mapping, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I need to create a 3D map with an ArDrone 2.0 in real time (while the drone's still acquiring data), but its camera doesn't have a depth sensor, otherwise the RGBDSLAM would be a good choice, i guess. I've read some [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471866/creating-a-3d-map-with-2d-depth-images-in-processing) about that but didn't find a way to do it online.
I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnuQzP3gty4) video about monocular SLAM but it creates a depth map only.

Is there a package that i could use to help me with that?

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213405/generation-online-3d-map-from-a-rgb-camera/) by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-10**:
Why is the map built from LSD-SLAM not enough? The output map is point cloud.

**Comment by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on 2015-07-10**:
Thanks for your response! Is this choice the better one since i need a 3D map to navigate through? I'm looking for more options to consider. (PS.: This package works for ROS indigo and fuerte, i'm using the hydro version, is that a problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, since you want to navigate, the map is quite important.

[tum_ardrone](http://vision.in.tum.de/data/software/tum_ardrone) is a good starting point, but instead of PTAM, you can try [ORB SLAM](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM). ORB SLAM works for ROS Hydro, so it might be a good choice.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on 2015-07-17**:
Unfortunately the probabilistic semi-dense mapping module isn't available for ORB SLAM yet, so i don't know a way to create the 3D map with this package, i'm testing LSD SLAM instead.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-19**:
Yeah, but the navigation part might not be easy. Have fun!